# How to declare a variable as a result of a function?

Tags: postgresql, function, variables, variable-declaration, create-function

I am currently making a function, and I need to declare a variable as a result of an other function within my *main_function*.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION main_function(t_name varchar) 
RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE
    var_1 varchar := execute format('select var_1 from sub_function(%s)' ,t_name);
BEGIN
    --do something with var_1
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

My *sub_function* returns one row with three colums.

```
select var_1 from sub_function()
```

returns only one result. I would like to store that result in the variable *var_1* because I will need it later. 
It is also important that this *sub_function* operates with the *t_name* variable, which I get from the *main_function*'s argument.
I have tried to do it in many different ways, for example without the execute function.

```
var_1 varchar := format('select var_1 from sub_function(%s)' ,t_name);
```

Unfortunately this one returns the whole text "select var_1 from sub_function('soimething')" and not the result of the query.
What should I do?
Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Dynamic SQL is completely unnecessary here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***return_column_name*** is the column your function should return. I don't know the name since you have said your function returns 3 columns. FYI, you can get all three values by using select ... into va1, var2, var3

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION main_function(t_name varchar) 
RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE
    var_1 varchar;
BEGIN
    select <return_column_name> from sub_function(t_name)  into var_1;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Link to [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)